# Wisdom in FFTW doesn't import/export

Tags: gcc, fftw

I am using FFTW for FFTs, it's all working well but the optimisation takes a long time with the `FFTW_PATIENT` flag.  However, according to [the FFTW docs](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Words-of-Wisdom_002dSaving-Plans.html#Words-of-Wisdom_002dSaving-Plans), I can improve on this by reusing wisdom between runs, which I can import and export to file.  (I am using the floating point fftw routines, hence the fftwf_ prefix below instead of fftw_)

So, at the start of my `main()`, I have :

```
char wisdom_file[] = "optimise.fft";
fftwf_import_wisdom_from_filename(wisdom_file);
```

and at the end, I have:

```
fftwf_export_wisdom_to_filename(wisdom_file);
```

(I've also got error-checking to check the return is non-zero, omitted for simplicity above, so I know the files are reading and writing correctly)

After one run I get a file `optimise.fft` with what looks like ASCII wisdom.  However, subsequent runs do not get any faster, and if I create my plans with the `FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY` flag, I get a null plan, showing that it doesn't see any wisdom there.

I am using 3 different FFTs (2 real to complex and 1 inverse complex to real), so have also tried import/export in each FFT, and to separate files, but that doesn't help.

I am using FFTW-3.3.3, I can see that FFTW-2 seemed to need more setting up to reuse wisdom, but the above seems sufficient now- what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have also tried `fftwf-wisdom -o ~/wisdomf rof2048 rob2048` (those are the sizes of FFT I need) and then imported the resulting `wisdomf` or copying it to `/etc/fftw` and using `fftwf_import_system`, with the same result.  The file looks valid, but fftw doesn't seem to use its contents.

Comment: I am in a similar position. If you were able to solve this, how did you do it?

Comment: @SgrA Unfortunately I didn't solve it. It was an intermediate stage of development, and wasn't required for the final version so I just lived with the startup delay. I hope you have better success!